# Mandatory last word with optional preceding words/phrases in Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble with the following regular expression in Java. I've removed the doubling up on quotes to make it a bit more readable. I've also put each "component", for lack of a better word, on a separate line (but the actual expression would have the lines merged with no spaces between them):

> (?:\bIN(?:\s*,)?)?
>   (?:\bVOL.?(?:U[NM]TARY)?)?(?:\s*,)?
>   \b(?:LIQ'N|LIQ|LQD|LIQD|LIQN|LIQUIDA|LIQUIDATION|REC|RECEIVERSHIP|RECSHIP|WINDING UP)\b

Essentially, the last word/expression is mandatory, but the preceding words IN and VOLUNTARY (or some version of it) are optional. Here's some examples of the strings that I would like this pattern to match:

> IN VOLUNTARY LIQUIDATION
>   IN VOL LIQ
>   IN VOL.LIQ
>   IN LIQUIDATION
>   IN LIQ
>   VOL LIQ
>   VOL.LIQ
>   VOL. LIQ
>   IN     LIQ
>   IN      VOL      LIQUIDATION
>   IN LIQUIDATION
>   IN LIQ
>   IN, VOL. LIQ
>   IN VOLUMTARY, LIQN
>   LIQUIDATION
>   RECEIVERSHIP

These phrases will be mixed into strings, and I need to remove them. These phrases will usually have be enclosed with `[` and `]` or `(` and `)`, but that's not a certainty, which is why I'm using word boundary markers.

I'm having trouble detecting the preceding words, only the last word is matched. Note that performance of the regex is not a major concern to me (i.e. this'll be a background process that can take it's time, if necessary). Can any regex gurus help me out with this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier at this point to just add your search terms in a collection and iterate/replace any present in the text you're parsing?

Comment: But there's so many possibilities, which is why I thought a regex would be so much more concise. Plus, I will very likely be discovering more terms that need to be removed in the future, which could increase the number of possibilities drastically. Surely this isn't beyond the capabilities of regular expressions?

Comment: That's *exactly* why I wouldn't advise for a regex :D Imagine 1 year from now, when your list contains a gazillion synonyms and similar terms, and your already semi-unreadable regex grows tenfold... If instead you have a set of terms to remove persisted somewhere, you'd be much better off knowing that you just need to add one more term to it and be done with it. Edit - also that would play much better with unit testing...

Comment: @Mena Well, that's a reasonable point, but I don't think I'd like to abandon regexes completely. There's still a good of unpredictable variability with regard to whitespace and placing of potential comma in the phrase. That wouldn't play well with static strings. I might consider a hybrid approach of a collection of phrases plugged into regexes to handle the whitespace etc.

Comment: you could definitely have a collection of patterns instead - literals when no pattern applies, and maintain that (e.g. what initially is a literal can become a pattern once you find similar cases you want to generalize, etc.). That would make things a lot easier to read than a single monolithic pattern. Might mean a little overhead in performance too though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using regex101 debugger one can see that the sequence `\s*,` fails, maybe you wanted `[\s,]*`: replacing `(?:\s*|,)?` with `[\s,]*`.

[original regex](https://regex101.com/r/iTA2jw/3)

[the functionning regex](https://regex101.com/r/iTA2jw/2)

Comment: Bingo! In fact that's even better, because it catches multiple commas with potential whitespace in between them. Thanks!